# Jsoup select is not returning all nodes

Tags: java, jsoup

I have just started using jsoup with this [site](http://www.raroyalties.org/covered-rec-title_SR.php?l=a) and something weird is happening.

All I want is to select the text under the column title, which you can find with the following html:

```
<div class="Table1_A1 grow clear-fix">
    <div class="grd-col grd-col-1a"> … </div>
    <div class="grd-col grd-col-2b">
       <p>
         <span class="T1">
                <a href="...."> TITLE TEXT IS HERE
                </a>
          </span>
        </p>
     </div>
     ...
</div>
```

Looking at this html structure I came up with the following for jsoup selection:

```
try {
  Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  Elements as = htmlDocument.select("div.grow > div.grd-col-2b > p > span.T1 > a");
  System.out.println(as.html());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the thing: It only prints out until title "ASAP", but there's loads after that, and they simply don't come up. So I am left wondering, does jsoup ".select()" have a limit on the nodes it returns? I have no idea how to come around this, any help is quite appreciated.

Comment: how many elements are there in your query? maybe some of the html components are loaded by javascript? if that's the case they won't show up in JSOUP since it takes a static page as input

Comment: None of the content is loaded through js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jsoup has no limitations for selects, but there is a default limitations for the body size of the request which is 1MB. This should fix the problem:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(60000).maxBodySize(10*1024*1024).get();
```

Comment: GENIUS! Much much appreciated!